# Google Analytics Onclick button for Event Tracking

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have an index page and I am planning to put a Subcribe button below. When the viewers key in their email and click on the button. The record is supposed to be an event the Google analytics that is allowed me to track. However,I am having the error in getting the data from this. The code is below:

The code is below:

```
    <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-87810245-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
      <script>

$('#sub-form').on('post', function(event) {
  // Prevent the browser's default form submission action.
  event.preventDefault();

  ga('send', 'event', {
    eventCategory: 'subscribe',
    eventAction: 'post',
    eventLabel: 'subscribe sent',
    hitCallback: function() {
      $('sub-form').trigger('post');
    }
  });
});
      </script>
```

The code for the button:

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <p>We specialize in all flower arrangements</p> 
  <form class="form-inline" id="sub-form">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" size="50" placeholder="Email Address" required>
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="post" class="btn btn-danger" id="post" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'subscribe', 'post', 'subscribe sent', 10);">Subscribe</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

However, the result is not shown in the Google Analytics.
[image]

The form result is my another event.

Comment: Did you debug it and see that the code executed?

Comment: It says "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" for my  "$('#sub-form').on('post', function(event) {"

Comment: That's mean you should add the jQuery library script. `$` -> jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working now after I remove my form class. I changed it to `<form action="thankyou.html" id="sub-form">`

Answer (score 0):

The script should be initiated first and then you should invoke your $('#sub-form'). Check your jquery initialisation too.

BTW: Did you look at this tool? www.customerlabs.co - it can get your job done in less than 5 mins without the need of the coding.